# iOS view controller lifecycle when using background threads

Tags: iphone, multithreading, ios

I am unclear on how to handle the following scenario...

Assume that you have a ViewController that needs to perform a long running operation.  The ViewController calls performSelectorInBackground to start the long running operation, which in turn will call performSelectorOnMainThread when it is done.  Now, assume that the View gets deallocated during the long running operation, perhaps because the user navigated backward in the UINavigationController.  When the background operation completes, it is going to try to send a message to a deallocated object.

What is the best way to handle this? It is in my requirements that the user must be able to abandon the screen during the operation, so preventing the backward navigation is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`performSelectorInBackground` retains the receiver, meaning you won't have any problem of operating on a deallocated object.

Read about it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorInBackground%3awithObject%3a)

Comment: Oh nice. I did not realize that. There should be no problems, then.

Comment: I didn't either, I missed the fine print :-)  Thank you for the answer!

Comment: You might want to have a way to tell that the viewController is gone and go ahead and cancel the operation since you no longer need the results - instead of letting it run to completion and calling a viewController that is no longer visible.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this would be to setup a thread manually instead of just using performSelectorInBackground. You would then start this operation on that thread and if at any point, the view that called this thread is destroyed, you would either kill the thread or send a message to it saying to clean up and stop the current task. Worst case is you could just set a variable that would be checked before sending the message to the view to make sure it is still around (but make sure the variable is thread safe).

Comment: I don't think he wants to allow the view controller to be deallocated while this thread is running. At least, that's how I interpreted the question.

Comment: If that is the case, then he should not be running the logic with the viewController. If the action being performed is for the viewController then he would want the operation to end when the view controller is no longer going to be shown. If it is just a generic operation that pertains to the app as a whole, then it should be done with a controller that will be around still when the viewController is deallocated.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear on that point.  I don't want to prevent the view from going away, I just don't want the "I'm finished" callback to be sent to the view if it has been deallocated.

Comment: Oh ok, so does this operation pertain to the view? Is the view going to do anything when it receives the signal?

Comment: Yes, the view would display the result of the operation.

Comment: Oh ok, so the only way that my suggestion is any improvement over just letting the thread run would be that you could free up any memory and stop the cpu usage earlier if you kill the thread on deallocation of the view.

Answer (score 0):

In the method that's being performed in the background, why don't you just retain `self` at the beginning and release it at the end? That way the view controller won't get deallocated. You could run into the problems, though, if the user navigates back to that view controller again and continues going forward and backward a lot. You'll have tons of threads executing.

Comment: I have read that the approach you suggest will not work, because in this scenario the final release would be performed on the background thread, which is a Bad Thing.

Comment: `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(release) withObject:nil];` =)

Answer (score 0):

Have the controller track the visibility of the view in `viewWillAppear:` and `viewWillDisappear:`. The background task should only update the view if it is visible.

```
if (self.viewIsVisible) {
    // update view
}
```